# How to correct a syntax error in SQL trigger near NEW?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have written a simple trigger that calls a `calculateMarketPriceCars` function (it has four int arguments):

```
CREATE TRIGGER calculateMarketPrTriggerCars
AFTER INSERT ON FOR_SALE_CARS
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculateMarketPriceCars(NEW.BOUGHT_PRICE, NEW.YEAR_OF_PRODUCTION, (SELECT 
NUMBER_OF_CARS_PRODUCED FROM ABSTR_CARS WHERE ABSTR_CARS.ABSTR_CAR_ID = NEW.ABSTR_CAR_ID), 
NEW.MILEAGE);
```

I doublechecked all the spellings and called the function manually separately from the trigger - everything else works correctly. But when I try to create the trigger (giving the above command to SQL) it shows

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 4: EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculateMarketPriceCars(NEW.BOUGHT_PRICE,...
```

Can NEW be not visible inside the brackets? How can I correct it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Trigger syntax is database-specific.

Comment: Edited. It's PostgreSQL 9.6.1.

Comment: The `create trigger` statement cannot reference pseudo-table `new`. The trigger *function* can. You would need to show us the code of the trigger function, and explain the logic.

Comment: Can I use a simple SQL-function here or should I use only a trigger-one?

Comment: What you really need to do is read the docs [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 1):

A trigger consists of two statements in PostgreSQL: the definition of the trigger function and the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. You cannot have both in a single statement.

You cannot write a trigger function in SQL, you have to use PL/pgSQL or another procedural language.